# How can set exposure time for DMM 27UJ003-ML camera using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I'm using a camera  which is called `DMM 27UJ003-ML`and the documents are available via [this link](https://www.theimagingsource.com/products/board-cameras/usb-3.0-monochrome/dmm27uj003ml/). This camera has some features such as  `Brightness` which can be set in `OpenCV`, see the following code for instance

```
//Header 
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   VideoCapture cap(0);   //Access to camera with ID = 0
   double brightness = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS); // get value of brightness
   cout<<brightness<<endl;   //print brightness value in console
}
```

result is `0.5` and it's OK,I can set `Brightness` as well, but if i want to change `Exposure time` the problem will be appear!!(`Exposure time` is another camera property that can be variable)

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,0.1);
}
```

But`Exposure time` can't be set in appropriate way and if want to use `get` method to knowing what set as `Exposure time` value,result is strange

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
double Exposure = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE);
cout<<Exposure<<endl;
```

result of `Exposure` is `inf` and camera doesn't response to outside environment(it seems that `Exposure time` is `inf` actually) so the only way to reset `Exposure time`is software that company gave to me and i don't know how i can set this feature in `opencv`

thanks for your help.

Comment: Found [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/96137/is-there-any-range-of-values-for-the-exposure-flag/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Linux based machine you can install a package that will help you about that, which it's name is v4l2ucp,this package can be install by below command in ubuntu

```
sudo apt install v4l2ucp
```

this is a package that give you graphical control on camera with using great `v4l2` package *(by installing v4l2ucp there is no need to install `v4l2` again)*. if you can change exposure time in the `v4l2ucp` then you can use `v4l2` inside of your program.

you can get whole information about your camera by below command in ubuntu terminal.

```
v4l2-ctl --all
```

after knowing which parameters are available for you by using above command you can change value of that parameter. for example of my output is like below

```
 brightness (int)    : min=-10 max=10 step=1 default=0 value=0
```

you can see there is a variable of camera,which it's name is brightness and defalut value of that is 0 and there is boundary for value (min=-10, and max =10) so how can I set this value to 10 for instance? I can do this by below command(please test it by open camera)

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl brightness=10
```

after doing that in terminal you can see brightness changes in camera.

So how we could use v4l2 command inside `Qt` programming? by using `QProcess` class, this command let you to run terminal commands inside of Qt program. I write a simple example

```
 #include <QProcess>
 int main()
 {
     QProcess process;
     process.start("v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl brightness=10");
     pro.waitForFinished(-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code at the beginning:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE,0.25);
```

`0.25` means 'manual mode'.